# Software to join exchangable images to a single image of A4 dimensions for printing

Tags: windows, png

Basically I want to arrange ~10 *(11 is probably impossible due to non-printable area)* images of sizes say 813 x 1185px (png format) on a canvas, which ultimately is being printed on A4 paper (so that I can cut the images out later). I already thought of a possible arrangement like this.

The actual problem is that I want to *easily* exchange any of the images for different images of the exact same size.

How can I do this or what software for Windows does that?

---

Motivation: These are "trading cards".

Comment: Maybe I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do ... But why not just use a regular layout program like Scribus or Indesign? If you're more into "programming" this you could use ImageMagick?

Comment: Margin between images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) from the `montage` command line facilities to size and arrange into a grid as a mosaic from the command line - the good news is that you are not restricted to one size or format of input format.

Note that to minimise the waste of paper and ease cutting out you are probably best using 9 (3x3) or 12 (3x4) grids.

Montage can be told to automatically resize the input images as required and to leave spaces between them. See the [help pages](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#montage) for more information.

If you put your commands into a batch script file that has the settings that you wish to use in you can supply it with 9 names at a time to produce the output file.

ImageMagick is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform *Windows, OS-X & Linux*
- Widely Used
- [Can be used](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php) for personal, company internal, or commercial purposes
- Supports over 200 image formats *for at least input*
- Can do a **lot** more

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Word? Put all images in place on a page and then right click the images and there should be an option to replace the image. You could easily put the images in a table and change the table color to white to hide the lines (if preferable).